# SED: How can I print every line after first instance of string using Sed?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have a file with a similar format...

```
16:28 asdfasdf
16:29 4398upte
16:30 34liuthr
16:31 34tertio
```

How can I use SED to print out every line including and after the line with "16:30"?

The result would be...

```
16:30 34liuthr
16:31 34tertio
```

Right now, I am using sed as follows, but I have to manually find the first line's line number e.g. "562697":

```
sed -n '562697,$p'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Addresses in `sed` can be either line numbers or patterns.  Try this:

```
sed -n '/16:30/,$p'
```

If the pattern contains a `/`, you can escape it with a `\`.  For example, to search for `16/30` instead of `16:30`, try this:

```
sed -n '/16\/30/,$p'
```

Comment: What if I needed to search 16/30? I'm not sure how to modify the syntax in this case. Thanks!

Comment: @barrrista I've edited my answer to show how to escape the character with a backslash.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Use a regular expression in the address:

```
sed -n '/^16:30/,$p'
```

or

```
sed '/^16:30/,$!d'
```